# Loop over a column and remove characters - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

This may be really trivial but I'm struggling to get anywhere with it.

So basically I have a column of ID's where some values are alphanumeric and some contain text prefixed before the alphanumeric value. How do I loop through that specific column and check whether the alphanumeric value has been prefixed with a string and then remove that string accordingly.

This is the way I was doing it but it's not working, nor is it the smart way to do it:

```
document[ID] = document[ID].replace("ReferenceNode, Objectid:", '')
```

Example:

```
ID
5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
ReferenceNode, ObjectID: 5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
```

Expected Output:

```
ID
5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
5d61527f0928c99f3cf10829
```

Comment: when I try `df['ID'].replace("ReferenceNode, ObjectID:", '',regex=True)` in your df it works. But glad you found your answer. maybe `ObjectID` should be used based on your data not `Objectid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.map()` for your task:

```
document['ID'] = document['ID'].map(lambda x: x.replace("ReferenceNode, Objectid:", ''))
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works perfectly, strange why it doesn't work with just replace

Comment: Make sure marking this answer as correct if that helped :)